# Sequelize update to v4 throws Error: models.User appears to be a function

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I have recently updated from v3 to v4 of the sequelize ORM. I have followed the upgrade guide, but am still facing issues. I have based this on the [`express-example`](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/).

this is the **models/index.ts**:

```
export var db: DbConnection = {};
export var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING);
var basename = path.basename(module.filename);
fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function (file) {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
    })
    .forEach(function (file) {
        var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model['name']] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db['sequelize'] = sequelize; db['Sequelize'] = Sequelize;

export default <DbConnection>db;
```

and here is **models/user.ts**:

```
export default function defineUser(sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define<UserInstance, UserAttributes>('User', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      validate: { isEmail: true }
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    role: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['Admin', 'Operator', 'Member']
    }
  });

  User.beforeCreate(function (user: UserInstance, options) {
    return hashPassword(user.password).then(function (hashedPw) {
      user.password = hashedPw;
    });
  })
  return User;
};

function hashPassword(password: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(5, function (err, salt) {
      if (err) { reject(err); }

      bcrypt.hash(password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) { reject(err); }
        resolve(hash);
      })
    });
  })
};
```

However, I still get error:

> Unhandled rejection Error: models.User appears to be a function. Perhaps you are importing model factory function? You should then use sequelize.import to create your model, see https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js#L17
>       at Loader.loadFixture (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\myProj\node_modules\sequelize-testing-fixtures\lib\loader.js:39:15)

What am I doing wrong?

## Update:

I also tried `module.exports = function defineUser(...`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to fix the DataTypes for email and password. Also you might what to use module.export instead of the function.

```
email: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING, //change to DataTypes.STRING
  unique: true,
  validate: { isEmail: true }
},
password: Sequelize.STRING, //change to DataTypes.STRING
role: {
  type: DataTypes.ENUM,
  values: ['Admin', 'Operator', 'Member']
}
```

Comment: and indeed with `module.exports = function defineUser(`